# Transient props react warring 'Invalid attribute name'

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using transient props from styled-components to prevent rendering and passing them to the elements (https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props)
But React still shows different waring: `Invalid attribute name: $attrName`

How can I avoid this warning message?

code:

```
interface ListItemProps {
  $item: boolean
}
export const ListItem = styled(ListItemBase)<ListItemProps>(({ $item }) => ({
 color: $item ? 'blue' : 'red'
}))
```

```
<ListItem $item={true} />
```

Comment: Have you installed the styled-components types package? `@types/styled-components`

Comment: The same is occurring with me. "styled-components": "^5.3.5","@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26". I haven't found a solution yet!

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error using [transient props](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props). I wasn't understanding it at all because I had used that in another project and it worked fine.

Reading carefully the code I realized that for the component I was getting the warning the prop **styled** was exported from **Material UI** and not from **Styled Components**, so that's why transient props weren't working here!

So make sure you're importing **styled** from **Styled Components**

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
```

and not from other libraries like I was -_-

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material';
```